# Disable short ticks on annotation_logticks

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, tikz

Is it possible to omit the short ticks when using `annotation_logticks`?
I.e., I want only the ticks for 10 and 5, not the 1 ticks.

I tried setting `short=unit(0,"cm")`. However, the short ticks still show up as dots.

If it is not possible with `annotation_logticks` are there other ways to achieve this?

Example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(scales)
tikz("test.pdf",standAlone=TRUE,12,3)
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=step,y=opsPerSecond,fill=hidx)) +   
        geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
        scale_y_continuous(
                trans = log10_trans(),
                breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))
        ) +
        annotation_logticks(sides="lr",short=unit(0,"cm"))
```

Here is a picture of the problem:
[image]

As you see, the dots on the axis are still visible, even with `short=unit(0,"cm")`!

PS: I use the tikz engine as output.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Setting `short = unit(0, "mm")` in the very last example in `?annotation_logticks` works fine for me.

Comment: @Henrik: Added it. Also added a picture of the resulting PDF.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. I realised it was the `theme_bw` in the `?annotation_logticks` example which draws a black box around the plot and covered 'the dots'. If I run the example with default theme the dots are visible. You may wish use that example in your post to make it reproducible and easy for people to play around with.

Comment: @Henrik: I have even left out `theme_bw()` in my minimal example. However, the picture I posted is even with `theme_bw()` (you notice the box and the white background) and the dots are still visible if you zoom in.

Comment: In [the code for `annotation_logticks`](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/annotation-logticks.r), `segmentsGrob`s are drawn at `start = 0, shortend = short` (which appear as dots when both start and end is zero). Perhaps you find an easy way to modify the code. Or quick'n'dirty: make the box/axis slightly thicker to cover the dots...

Comment: Please also post a minimal data set required to fully reproduce the plot. Or use one of built-in sets like `iris` or `mtcars`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `iris` to reproduce your problem, and it seems the solution is

```
annotation_logticks(sides="lr", short = unit(NA, "cm"))
```